# Docker filter containers both by image name and age

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to stop / prune docker containers according to 2 conditions:

- image name
- time they've been running for

For instance, I could want to stop all containers from image image-name that have been running for over 24h.

By reading the documentation, it seems the `--filter` option is not consistent at all since `docker container prune` has the `until` filter, which is useful to filter containers by age but doesn't have the `ancestor` filter. This filter is available for `docker ps` though, and it filters by image name. If I could run `docker ps` with `until`, I could just pipe the ids to `docker stop` but again, the filters are not consistent between commands.

Finally, `docker container prune` has a `label` filter but I can't seem to find what a label is in docker or if it could be useful in this case. I tried `label=image=<image-name>` without success.

Update: I've realized `docker container prune` does not have a way of removing running containers, only stopped ones, so I'd need to find a way to fitler by age on `docker ps`

Comment: Something so basic as this shouldn't require python and a whole SDK... even more when they seem to have the filter for some commands... Let's see if someone knows a way. I'll post it on Docker's slack or forums as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in comment it is not possible to handle removing with only docker command, but it is possible handle it with one line bash command:

```sh
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}|{{.Image}}|{{.CreatedAt}}" | grep "imagename" | grep -v "$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" | awk -F'|' '{print$1}' | xargs)
```

- `grep "imagename"` → filter lines with `imagename` only
- `grep -v "$(date +%Y-%m-%d)"` → get only containers that created not today (It can't be tomorrow by design so only yesterday or earlier cases are possible)
- `awk -F'|' '{print$1}'` → get only container ID and remove unnecessary information (image ID, date)
- `xargs` will replace new lines with whitespaces
- `docker rm -f` will remove IDs provided with `$(docker ps ...)` comamnd

But this command is little bit different than you want. It will remove all yesterday's containers even if it created 1 minute ago (if container created at 23:59 and you run this command at 00:00)
So you may add one another `grep`: `| grep -v $(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date="1 days ago")`. That will allow to keep containers running less than ~48 hours

---

#### Update: handle removing with hour level

```sh
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}|{{.Image}}|{{.CreatedAt}}" | grep "imagename" | egrep -v "$(printf "$(for i in {1..24}; do echo $i' hour ago'; done)" | date +'%Y-%m-%d %H' -f - | sed -z 's/\n/|/g' | sed 's/.$//')" | awk -F'|' '{print$1}' | xargs)
```

command remove all containers that created not in previous 24 hours from now

＊tested at Ubuntu. This command may not work in Unix-based systems (include MacOS) because different `sed` syntax

Comment: this is not very flexible when it comes to the date threshold though right? if you want to target containers older than 7 days, for instance, or older than 12 hours, this would not work. Even if I wanted to remove those over 24 hours this would only work if I ran the command right before midnight

Comment: Yes. it is not possible to compare dates without using `for` or `while`. However you able to add dates as more as you want by adding `| grep $(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date="N days ago")`. I updated my answer with this information

Comment: (about the edit) maybe I am wrong but how does this remove any container older than 48 hours? it just targets those containers started during a specific day (which is 1 day ago) but not all those before that. If I run this everynight, it could be enough. I would need to manually remove any older container manually the first time though

Comment: anyways, it is a simpler solution with just this drawback so it is not bad

Comment: I mean that you need to add many `grep`'s: `| grep -v "$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" | grep $(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date="1 days ago") | grep $(date +"%Y-%m-%d" --date="2 days ago")`. Here `-v` means all except `this` and `this` are three dates: `today`, `yesterday`, `day before yesterday`. All another containers will be deleted. Also you may use `grep -v -e DATE -e DATE` to set multiple dates within one pipe

Comment: `it just targets those containers started during a specific day` → Yep. I forget to add `-v` in my answer (updated)

Comment: oh okey! it's the opposite then, e.g. remove any  container that was not created today or yesterday, for instance. It is good! not useful for specific hours (or less than a day) but good!

Comment: `not useful for specific hours (or less than a day)` → Actually you may set 24 `grep` pipes (or 24 `-e DATE HOUR` arguments) with `date +"%Y-%m-%d %H"` format to be able handle deleting with hour level, but it is some kind of gick perversion :)

Comment: @raquelhortab Finally I created command that will remove containers created `not at previous 24 hours`

Answer (score 0):

So, it'd be nice to be able to do this only using docker commands but for now  I found a way using bash and awk:

```
containers=$(docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}###{{.Image}}###{{.CreatedAt}}" | grep "imagename")

date_limit="2022-05-19"
while IFS= read -r line; do

    id="$(echo $line | awk '{split($0,a,"###"); print a[1]}')"
    image="$(echo $line | awk '{split($0,a,"###"); print a[2]}')"
    date="$(echo $line | awk '{split($0,a,"###"); print a[3]}')"
    
    echo "Container $id with date $date and image $image"
    
    echo $line | if [[ "$date" < "$date_limit" ]]; 
    then echo "removing"; docker rm -f $id;
    else echo "not removing"; 
    fi
    
done <<< "$containers"
```

This prints the containers' ids, image name and date. Parses each line and compares the date with a threshold (date_limit) and compares the image name with the desired name. If the desired conditions are met, it removes the container (with -f flag, which kills the container if it's still running)

Comment: It is possible to little bit shorten your script, for example you may use: `containers=$(docker ps -a --format "{{.ID}}###{{.Image}}###{{.CreatedAt}}" | grep "imagename")` to get list of necessary containers only and remove `&& [[ "$image" == "imagename" ]]` check, but you have to use `bash` to compare dates. It is not possible to handle it with docker only command. Also you may use `docker inspect` to get extra info about container in JSON format and parse JSON by python, but it will be more complicated than current code